# Trouble connecting sockets between PCs

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm having issues getting a simple server/client socket app working in C# between two computers and I've begun to run out of ideas. I'm running windows XP on both machines and I've added exceptions to the firewall for both the port I've been trying to connect as well as the exe. The strange part is that it works perfectly with both client and server running on a single machine.

Server Code:

```
IPAddress ipAddress;
IPAddress.TryParse("127.0.0.1", out ipAddress);

IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 51000);
_ListenerSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
try
{
    _ListenerSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
    _ListenerSocket.Listen(1000);

    while (_Running)
    {
        _ListenerSync.Reset();
        _ListenerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), _ListenerSocket);
        _ListenerSync.WaitOne();
    }

    _ListenerSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    _ListenerSocket.Close();
}
```

Client Code:

```
tTarget = new Socket(_IP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
tTarget.Connect(_IP, 51000);
```

AcceptCallback is never being called. So something is rejecting the connection before that triggers. This client/server setup works for internal connections on a single computer (running both client and server on the same computer), but fails when trying to connect two machines together on a local network.

An exception is being thrown on the tTarget.Connect() call:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I've installed wireshark on both machines to make sure the packets are arriving, 106 being the client and 101 being the server.

```
262 24.724892   192.168.0.106   192.168.0.101   TCP brlp-2 > 51000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
263 24.724922   192.168.0.101   192.168.0.106   TCP 51000 > brlp-2 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
270 25.144866   192.168.0.106   192.168.0.101   TCP brlp-2 > 51000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
271 25.144887   192.168.0.101   192.168.0.106   TCP 51000 > brlp-2 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
288 25.647842   192.168.0.106   192.168.0.101   TCP brlp-2 > 51000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1
289 25.647874   192.168.0.101   192.168.0.106   TCP 51000 > brlp-2 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

Note: This is all the network communication on port 51000 before the exception is thrown.

Which looks like nothing is being blocked, and since it works on a single computer, I'm thinking it may be a setting on the socket which is not allowing connections from remote PCs. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind it to address 0.0.0.0. This means "all local addresses, whatever they are".

Hard-coding the local address is a bad, bad idea. Making it configurable is better, but only necessary if you want to explicitly allow for listening on some local addresses but not others. For enterprise grade server software this is sometimes a requirement (multihomed server scenarios and such).

Answer (score 3):

Use the server machine's IP address, not the [localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) address, 127.0.0.1.